# SSRS cascading parameters and multiple results

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, cascading

I have an SSRS report that uses cascading parameters, the second parameter is using a dataset against the results of the first.

1. If the first is set to `N` or `Y`, the second then is the same.
2. If the first is set to `None`, I'd like for the second to then be able `Y` or `N` on it's own, to have a subset of grouping.

The first parameter sets several others to `Y` to create a grouping level, and the second one only has `<Select a value>` if the first is set to `None`.

Comment: Can you share the datasets for the parameters? Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to have the 2nd parameter return `N` and `Y` if the 1st parameter is `None`? Also, are you wanting to change the default or available value(s)?

Comment: Hello, First parameter has 3 available values: Y, N and None, second parameter uses a dataset against the first, so if First is set to Y or N, the second default to Y or N. But if first is N, I'd also like to be able to then change the second to be Y, but currently it's default value uses the dataset, so it is locked to the result of the first. (Basically, this report has 7 params, the first needs to set the second to work, but the second can be used by itself as well)